# Is there a (hopefully free) graphing utility BESIDES mathematica that can graph log polar coordinates?

Tags: logarithms, math-software

This is my first post to the forum. I have had a good experience with other stackexchange fora, so I have high hopes for this one.

I have looked online and can not seem to find the software described in the title.

Does it exist?

I am also thinking along the lines of plug-ins for gimp or other graphics software that might be able to accomplish this task.

Any information would be helpful.

Comment: You're aware that plotting $\rho = f(\theta)$ in log polar coordinates is equivalent to plotting $r = e^{f(\theta)}$ in polar coordinates, yes?

Comment: gnuplot has this possibility

Comment: Scilab has [polarplot](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.0/en_US/polarplot.html) and exports graphics in various formats. You can exponentiate the data and assign the position of tickmarks.